# Put jquery with django rest api

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update my data via ajax jquery.

When I use the api to update the data it works correctly. But when I try to use ajax put it does not update.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: "/api/attend/" + this.props.id + ".json",
            headers: { 'Authorization': "Token " + token },
            data: JSON.stringify({attend_ts: '2016-07-05T13:44:21.855910Z'}),
            success: (result) => {
                console.log("success")
            },
            error: function (cb) { cb }
        });
```

The data does not update, but jquery returns success at the console.

Comment: What *does* it do? any errors? do you have support for `PUT` on the back end?

Comment: This update my database and I have support for PUT on the back end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, I set the dataType:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: "/api/attend/" + this.props.id + ".json",
            headers: { 'Authorization': "Token " + localStorage.token },
            data: {
                report: 'test'
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: (result) => {
                console.log("success")
            },
            error: function (cb) { cb }
});
```

report is a field from my database